# Javascript Negative Lookaround

Tags: regex

I want to match ___ except within {}:

https://regex101.com/r/PYRWIA/1

I don't understand why it match though with

```
/___\s*\n*(?!})/
```

Comment: You can use: `___(?!\s*})`

Comment: or `___\s+(?!})` would also work

Comment: @anubhava thanks yours work will use that :) can you explain why mine doesn't still ?

Comment: `\s*` will let negative lookahead condition being met right after last dash since next character is a line break not `}`

Comment: @anubhava thanks it's clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIrst of all there is no need to use `\n` in your regex since `\s` matches line break also.

Second issue is with use of `*` (0 or more occurrences) in your regex since `\s*` will let negative lookahead condition being met right after last dash since next character is a line break not `}`.

You can use any of these 2 patterns:

```sh
___(?!\s*})

___\s+(?!})
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYRWIA/2)

Comment: This one is not *within* https://regex101.com/r/PYRWIA/3

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: My answer is for fixing the OP's regex. For finding `___` outside any `{...}` can be done but requirements can vary like unbalanced brackets, allowing escaping etc

Comment: e.g. this would work in modern JS: `___(?!(?<={\s*___)\s*})`